# Does the "Re-Timer" device help to alleviate "winter blues"?

Tags: medical-science, consumer-products, psychiatry, light

The Re-Timer website [states](http://re-timer.com/treatment/winter-blues/):

> Re-Timer is a wearable light therapy device for Winter Blues.
>
> Winter Blues is a low-mood experienced primarily during the winter months. Symptoms can include loss of energy, weight gain and difficulty concentrating.
>
> Researchers from Flinders University state that Winter Blues is the result of a mis-timed circadian rhythm. Their research shows that bright light visual stimulation (light which enters the eyes), can change timing of the sleep-wake rhythm. Bright light therapy has been used to treat the range of conditions caused by a mis-timed body clock including winter blues.

...

> Simply wear Re-Timer for 30 minutes per day in the morning to help alleviate symptoms of winter blues such as low energy.
>
> Re-Timer is the only portable light therapy device which emits a patented green light proven to be superior for treating winter blues.
>
> A significant body of research has compared the efficacy of different wavelengths to treat winter blues. Green light provides a treatment effect superior to that of red light and similar to that seen in previous studies with white light. (Oren, Brainard et al. 1991)

I wonder whether the device alleviates Winter Blues symptoms as advertised; specificaly, whether its "patented (?!) green light" is indeed more effective then [standard light boxes](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14568/do-light-boxes-help-seasonal-affective-disorder), whether the lower brightness is really compensated by proximity of the device to the eyes and "optimal light delivery", and whether 30 minutes' use per day suffices. Specific evidence for this or a similar device would be perfect; if not available, general evidence as to the feasibility of such an approach would also be relevant. Any remarks on these and other claims are also welcome.

Comment: Is this a duplicate: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14568/do-light-boxes-help-seasonal-affective-disorder

Comment: @Oddthinking Thanks, that's a good start (no idea why I have missed it when searching for this). I'm editing the question to focus more specifically on the more claims of this device's manufacturers.